# Console.log() right after function call returns the function itself

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JS and I stumbled upon the following while practising and I wonder why this is happening.
I actually think I see why; however, I don't find it very straight forward.

I have this object and I'd like to generate a Username out of the Owner's name.

```
const account1 = {
  owner: 'Pat Racco',
  movements: [200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, 70, 1300],
  interestRate: 1.2, // %
  pin: 1111,
};
```

This is my attempt:

```
const createUsername = function (owner) {
  const username = owner
    .toLowerCase()
    .split(' ')
    .map(v => v[0])
    .join('');
  return username;
};
```

Now, why if I do this:

```
createUsername(account1.owner);
console.log(createUsername);
```

the result is the function itself; but if I do this:

```
    console.log(createUsername(account1.owner));
// "pr"
```

why does it work as expected?

Comment: There's some decent beginner guides in the Mozilla Developer Network Web Docs. Have a read of [Function return values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values) (and its prerequisites)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `createUsername` is the method(function) so it returns a function, whereas `createUsername(account1.owner)` executes the function (because of the brackets), so `console.log` displays the return value of the function.

You could also do this

```js
var result = createUsername(account1.owner);
console.log(result);
```

which will execute the function, assign it to `result` and output the `result` value in the console.